# Hashem calls people twice and Hinneni

Tags: tanach, rashi, theology

In many places in the Tanach Hashem uses a name twice (ie Avraham, Avraham in Breshit 22:11; Jacob Jacob in Breshit 46:2; Shmuel shmuel in Shmuel Aleph 3:10 and more).

Rashi says that this is an expression of affection.

With all due respect to Rashi I am not entirely happy with that answer.  If it is an expression of affection why isn't it used more?  If it is an expression of affection why at these times specifically?

As well, on a related note the call is often answered with Hinneni (commonly translated as Here I am).

Rashi explains that Hinneni is an expression of modesty and eagerness.

Again with all due respect to Rashi, why does this follow the expression of affection?  How do the double name calling and the Hinneni relate?

Comment: Full discussion of this topic here: http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=29511&st=&pgnum=26

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ילקוט שמעוני -
שמואל א - פרק ג - רמז צז

ויקרא כפעם בפעם. שמואל שמואל, אברהם אברהם יעקב יעקב משה משה לשון חבה לשון זרוז הן הן עד שלא נדבר עמם והן הן משדבר עמם, הן הן עד שלא נכנסו לגדולה והן הן משנכנסו לגדולה

Besides being an expression of affection it also shows that they remained the same even after Hashem spoke to them, and even after they were elevated to their positions.

Comment: see also http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12432/avraham-avraham-yaakov-yaakov-moshe-moshe-shmuel-shmuel-why-not-yitzchok-yi

Answer (score 0):

Let's take them case by case. Firstly [Sifra](https://www.sefaria.org/Sifra%2C_Vayikra_Dibbura_d%27Nedavah%2C_Chapter_1.12?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) says:

> "משה משה" (שמות ג, ד); "אברהם | אברהם" (בראשית כב, יא); "יעקב | יעקב"
> (בראשית מו, ב); "שמואל | שמואל" (שמואל א ג, י) – לשון חיבה, לשון
> זירוז. דבר אחר: הוא "משה" עד שלא נדבר עמו, הוא "משה" משנדבר עמו.
>
> "Moshe, Moshe," "Avraham, Avraham," "Yaakov, Yaakov," "Shmuel, Shmuel"
> — an **expression of affection** and of **prompting to zeal**. Another
> connotation: "Moshe, Moshe" — He is "Moshe" before being spoken to; he
> is (**the same, righteous**) "Moshe" after being spoken to.

Breshit 22:11: Avraham just passed the greatest of all tests, the Akeida. **A time of zeal and affection, and an indication that this difficulty didn't change Avraham.**

Breshit 46:2: The first time Hashem had spoken to Yaacov in many years (see Rashi [here](https://www.sefaria.org/Rashi_on_Genesis.45.27.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)), and was about to embark on the beginning of galut mitzraim. **A time of zeal and affection, and an indication that this difficulty didn't change Yaacov.**

Shmot 3:4: The first time Hashem ever spoke to Moshe, and was about to give him the mission of ending galut mitzraim. **A time of zeal and affection, and an indication that this difficulty didn't change Moshe.**

Shmuel 1:3:10: The first time Hashem ever spoke to Shmuel, and gave him a nevua about [blessings] for his master Eli. **A time of zeal and affection, and an indication that this difficulty didn't change Shmuel.**

The remaining question is, why only these places? I would like to know that too, but we must start by asking, what other places would it be appropriate?