# Why didn't Hashem call twice to Yitzchak like he did to other prophets?

Tags: names, avot-patriarch-fathers

*Avraham Avraham, Yaakov Yaakov, Moshe Moshe, Shmuel Shmuel - why not Yitzchok Yitzchok?*

> Related to [Hashem calls people twice and Hinneni](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12295/hashem-calls-people-twice-and-hinneni)

We find in Tanach that Hashem called Avraham Avraham, Yaakov Yaakov, Moshe Moshe, Shmuel Shmuel. Why if this is a language of affection (ילקוט שמעוני - שמואל א - פרק ג - רמז צז), and showing that the person remained the same even after Hashem spoke to them and even after they were elevated to their positions - why do we not find the same by Yitzchok?

Comment: I'd love an answer along the lines of Yitzhak as *din* / *gevurah* here.  I wonder if anyone speaks to/can speak to that.

Answer (score 3):

Midrash Mishlei (26:24):

> אמר ר' סימון בשעה שהיה עשו הרשע מתחנן לפני אביו, ואומר ברכני גם אני אבי, היה בדעתו לברכו יותר מיעקב אחיו, מיד הפליגתו רוח הקודש, אמרה לו, **יצחק יצחק** אל תאמין בחנוניו של רשע, שנאמר כי יחנן קולו אל תאמן בו כי שבע תועבות בלבו

or, in loose translation:

> Rabbi Simon said: When Esau, the evil one, was begging his father [Genesis 27:38] "bless me, too, my father", Isaac's intent was to bless Esau more than he had blessed Esau's brother, Jacob. Immediately, God's immanence traveled to him and said "**Isaac! Isaac!** Don't believe an evil person's begging", as it says [Proverbs 26:25] "When his voice begs, do not believe him, for his heart contains seven abhorrent things".

Comment: Beautiful. However this is not in Tanach, this is a Midrash. So the question remains.

Comment: Not every conversation between man and G-d was recorded in Tanach. Since according to Midrash, the addressing of Yitzchak by repeating his name did in fact occur, there isn't much of a question left.

Comment: what is midrash?