# What is "the twice-uttered (double-spoken) Name of Names"?

Tags: mysticism-kabbalah, shemos-sacred-names, hasidic-story

In S. Ansky's 1916 play [*The Dybbuk*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Dybbuk) — or at least in this English translation (from the Yiddish) by Fernando Peñalosa — there are two mentions in Act I of a "twice-uttered name of God":

> SECOND BATLEN. I didn't think there were any incantations or letter combinations with which you could summon Satan.
>
> THE MESSENGER. There is only one way the Devil can be summoned, and that is by means of the mighty **Twice-uttered Name of God,** whose flame fuses the loftiest mountain peaks into the deepest valleys.
>
> THIRD BATLEN. But isn't there danger in using the mighty Name of God?
>
> THE MESSENGER. Danger?... No... only the intense longing of the spark for the flame can shatter the vessel.

[...]

> KHONEN. Engagement?... [...] So it means that nothing helped, not the fasts, not the ablutions, or the letter combinations, not the mortifications of the flesh? Was it all in vain? [...] *(He clutches at his chest, stands up, with an ecstatic expression on his face.)* Ah, ah, ah! The secret of the great **Twice-uttered Name** is revealed to me! I... see it! I... I... I have won! *(Falls to the floor.)*

(Spoiler alert: Khonen dies and becomes a dybbuk possessing the body of his beloved.)

[John Hirsch's translation](https://archive.org/details/dybbuk00hirs/page/12/mode/2up) (which is radically different from Peñalosa's: ah, I see, it's more of an "adaptation for the modern stage") has similarly

> He can be summoned by **the great double-spoken Name of Names** that can unite the highest mountain peaks of Heaven with the deepest depths at the centre of the Earth.
>
> The secret of **the great double-spoken Name of Names** is revealed to me...

I assume this phrase refers to some bit of (early-20th-century Polish or Galician) Jewish folklore or Kabbala; but I haven't found anything on it online. Can anyone shed any light on the backstory here? Uttered twice by whom, and when?

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: Does the text mention anything about the 13 attributes of mercy? If so, I think we are referring to this: https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.34.6?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en, where Hashem's Great Name of Names is indeed said twice, the only time in the Torah.

Answer (score 1):

This probably doesn't either seem to answer your question; but when the Talmud in [gittin 68a](https://www.sefaria.org/Gittin.68a.12)
Relates that when benayahu was sent by king solomon to capture a demon he cried out to the demon twice that the name of G.od is upon the chain and therefore cannot be broken.

> נְחֵית, אֲתָא, שְׁדָא בֵּיהּ שׁוּשִׁילְתָּא, סְתָמֵיהּ. כִּי אִתְּעַר, הֲוָה קָא מִיפַּרְזַל; אֲמַר לֵיהּ: שְׁמָא דְמָרָךְ עֲלָךְ! שְׁמָא דְּמָרָךְ עֲלָךְ!
> Benayahu descended from the tree, came, and threw the chain around Ashmedai, and enclosed him within it. When Ashmedai awoke he struggled to remove the chain. Benayahu said to him: The name of your Master is upon you, the name of your Master is upon you, do not tear the chain. God’s name is written on this chain, and it is forbidden to destroy it.

I believe when the script of the play says "twice-uttered" it means to repeat one name in order to summon the devil.
The connection I see in this gemara is that G.ods name is used twice when "summoning" (hardly comparable to the play you referenced) a demon.

Answer (score 0):

Only thing I can think of is that G.od, when addressing his "beloved", calls to them twice.
See Exodus 3:4 for an example of this.

Comment: This answer could be improved by offering a source for that — again I assume you're alluding to some (scripture|folklore|literary) reference, but I'm not familiar with it.

Comment: @Quuxplusone this does not sound like it is addressing the question at all. However, you requested a source for what Shababnik said, I have collected all these double name calls in this answer: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/132432/31534

Comment: @RabbiKaii (and OP): Oh, thanks! I assumed OP's meaning was less literal, like a "postman always rings twice" kind of thing. But now I see, literally, ["Abraham, Abraham!" (Gen 22:11)](https://biblehub.com/genesis/22-11.htm), ["Jacob, Jacob!" (Gen 46:2)](https://biblehub.com/genesis/46-2.htm), ["Moses, Moses!" (Ex 3:4)](https://biblehub.com/exodus/3-4.htm), ["Samuel, Samuel!" (1 Sam 3:10)](https://biblehub.com/1_samuel/3-10.htm). I agree we have no evidence that it's relevant to the quote (or not); but I can see how it _might_ turn out to be.

Comment: Yeah. I see now that I misunderstood your question